# is Math.round or Date different for firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Is Math.round different for firefox? Or is Date different?

```
var p = Math.round(((today - start) / (end - start)) * 100);
```

In firefox `p` is "N/A" in crome it is a normal number. Why?
`today`, `start` and `end` are all `Date` objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math.round()` takes a number as parameter. Giving it a Date object does not make sense. See [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) and/or the ECMAScript [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.round).

Before calculating you should decide which unit you are operating on.  Nanoseconds, milliseconds, seconds, hours,...?

For example, to get the milliseconds portion of the today date object in universal time you can use:

`var milliseconds = today.getUTCMilliseconds();`

Comment: ok i think i know wat happened. new Date(String) gives not a number in firefox if it cant parse the string and crome returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

Why? Because Firefox has - in this case - implemented closer to the ECMAScript specs.